# Which event should I use to get the checkbox value which is in gridcontrol

Tags: c#, events, gridview, checkbox, devexpress

I have a Devexpress gridcontrol that has a checkbox column in it. I am trying to get the value of the checkbox value after user checks or unchecks one of the checkbox in any row. My problem is I am getting the always getting false value.

How can I get the correct value? what event should I use?

here is my code,

```
private void gvBobin_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
     setUsageSlipAndProductionEntryRelation();
}


public void setUsageSlipAndProductionEntryRelation() {

        for (int i = 0; i < gvBobin.RowCount -1; i++)
        {
            bool check_ = (bool)gvBobin.GetRowCellValue(i, "CHECK");
            if (check_ == true)
            {
                ...............   
            }
            else{
                ...............
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to immediately react to user actions, then you need to use `GridView.CellValueChanging` event. `GridView.CellValueChanged` event is fired only after user leaves the cell. In both cases to get the changed value you must use `CellValueChangedEventArgs` object `e` and its `Value` property and before getting value you must to check the column.

```
private void gvBobin_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "CHECK")
    {
        bool check_ = (bool)e.Value;

        if (check_)//There are no need to write check_ == True
        //You can use e.RowHandle with gvBobin.GetRowCellValue method to get other row values.
        //Example: object value = gvBobin.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle,"YourColumnName")
        {
            //...............
        }
        else
        {
            //...............
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to iterate through all rows then don't use `GridView.RowCount`. Use `GridView.DataRowCount` property instead.

```
for (int i = 0; i < gvBobin.DataRowCount -1; i++)
    //...............
```